# Ruby 1.9: Convert byte array to string with multibyte UTF-8 characters

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to find a way in Ruby to take a UTF-8 byte array and transform it back to a string.

In irb (Ruby 1.9.2 preview 3) I can create the correct byte array from UTF-8 string:

```
ruby-1.9.2-preview3 > 'Café'.bytes.to_a
 => [67, 97, 102, 195, 169]
```

However, I can't find a way to roundtrip from bytes back to an array. I tried to use Array.pack with the U* option, but that doesn't work for multibyte characters.

```
ruby-1.9.2-preview3 > [67, 97, 102, 195, 169].pack('U*')
 => "CafÃ©"
```

Does anybody know a way to take a UTF-8 byte array with multibyte characters and convert it back to a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This has to do with how `pack` interprets its input data. The `U*` in your example causes it to **convert** the input data (assumed to be in a default character set, I assume; I really couldn't find any documentation of this) to UTF-8, thus the double encoding. Instead, just pack the bytes and interpret as UTF-8:

```
irb(main):010:0> [67, 97, 102, 195, 169].pack('C*').force_encoding('utf-8')
=> "Café"
```

Answer (score 11):

You specifically ask about a byte array, but maybe codepoints are more suitable:

```
ar = 'Café'.codepoints.to_a
# => [67, 97, 102, 233]
ar.pack('U*')
# => Café
```

Comment: I might use that on another project, but for this one I start out with the byte array, and have to work back to the string.